# December/January Seasonal Mean

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-xarray, pandas-resample

I am attempting to calculate the seasonal means for the winter months of DJF and DJ. I first tried to use Xarray's .groupby function:

> ds.groupby('time.month').mean('time')

Then I realized that instead of grouping by the previous years' December and the subsequent Jan/Feb., it was grouping all three months from the same year. I was then able to figure out how to solve for the DJF season by resampling and creating a function to select out the proper 3 month period:

```
    >def is_djf(month):
            return (month == 12)
    >ds.resample('QS-MAR').mean('time')
    >ds.sel(time=is_djf(ds['time.month']))
```

I am still unfortunately unsure how to solve for the Dec./Jan. season since the resampling method I used was for offsetting quarterly. Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `resample` with `QS-DEC`.

Suppose this dataframe:

```
         time  val
0  2020-12-31    1
1  2021-01-31    1
2  2021-02-28    1
3  2021-03-31    2
4  2021-04-30    2
5  2021-05-31    2
6  2021-06-30    3
7  2021-07-31    3
8  2021-08-31    3
9  2021-09-30    4
10 2021-10-31    4
11 2021-11-30    4
12 2021-12-31    5
13 2022-01-31    5
14 2022-02-28    5
```

```
>>> df.set_index('time').resample('QS-DEC').mean()
            val
time
2020-12-01  1.0
2021-03-01  2.0
2021-06-01  3.0
2021-09-01  4.0
2021-12-01  5.0
```

Comment: Doesn't this still do the same as 'QS-MAR'? Im reading it as the first time stamp is DJF for 2020/2021, as the next time stamp starts on 2021-03-01? Now, Im hoping to do this same thing, except for the months of December and January only.

Comment: What you want is DJF, MAM, JJA, SON, that's right? with D from the previous year and so on? And yes QS-DEC, QS-MAR, QS-JUN, QS-SEP do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...I did want that yes, so that I may use the DJF season, although I found the solution for that portion. I also want to analyze the season of DJ as well but I am unsure how to isolate just those two months.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to set in the resampled dataframe the times to not be the times at the beginning of the season, but at the end of the season (means, instead of 2020-12-01 to have 2021-02-28)? thank you!

Comment: @NeStack. Does it what you expect: `df.set_index('time').resample('Q-FEB').mean()`?

Comment: Awesome, yes, your comment solved my issue! Tough, can you explain a bit how the syntax works and what is the difference between `Q` and `QS`? I guess the ``S` is for "start". Is there also something for "middle"? tnx

Comment: Q is quarter end and QS is quarter start :-) Check the documentation for more information: [Offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)